What is the difference between these two polymers?
I am looking at purchasing a chemical that will release a small amount of HF gas and have been referred to a polymer called PVPHF. After looking it up, though, it appears that there are two compounds which appear to be (almost) identical called PVPHF. Each has a different CAS number: 130495-33-9 and 79821-63-9. Respectively, on SciFinder, they are referred to as $\ce{(C7H7N)_x.\textit{x}(FH)_x}$ and $\ce{(C7H7N.FH)_x}$.
I do not know what the difference is between the two compounds.
I have asked a few other people and they can't work out what the difference is either.
Can anyone tell me whether these two chemicals are, in fact, the same, or whether there is a subtle difference that I am not seeing? I do see the x in front of the FH in the first compound, but I know nothing about polymers so I do not know if that means something special or not. Is it saying that there is more HF in the first compound than the second?
For the people whose first thought will be 'Just look at the structures', I would like to make it clear that I have, and they have confused me even more. For instance, for the structure of 130495-33-9, SciFinder represents it as this:

whereas Chemical Book represents it as this:

For the 79821-63-9 compound, SciFinder represents it as this:

whereas Merck/Sigma Aldrich represents it like this:

and Alfa chemical represents it like this:

Perhaps these structures will make it clear to some of you what the difference is between the two compounds, but I do not see much consistency between any of them, so any explanations would be appreciated.

It seems like PVPHF is a non-stoichiometric mixture of poly-4-vinylpyridine and hydrogen fluoride:

Poly-4-vinylpyridinium poly(hydrogen fluoride) (PVPHF), containing 35-60% hydrogen fluoride by weight, was prepared as a solid hydrogen fluoride equivalent reagent. PVPHF with 60% hydrogen fluoride by weight was found to be a versatile fluorinating agent for the hydrofluorination and bromofluorination of alkenes and alkynes, fluorination of alcohols as well as other fluorination reactions. Low hydrogen fluoride content PVPHF (3 equivalents of hydrogen fluoride to 1 equivalent of 4-vinylpyridine unit) was also found to be an efficient reagent for bromofluorination of alkenes in the presence of 1,3-dibromo-5,5-dimethylhydantoin. Fluorosulfonic acid-modified PVPHF showed enhanced reactivities for the fluorination of secondary alcohols.

Source: https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-1993-25924
The higher percentage corresponds roughly to 8 HF molecules per pyridine unit, and the lower to roughly 2.8. The first HF would protonate pyridine, turning it into pyridinium. This explains the notation $\ce{F(HF)_n-}$. One of the images pasted by the OP does not show the polymer but the reagent (the vinyl molecule with the double bond) instead.
Strangely, some of the datasheets for CAS-No 79821-63-9 give a formula ($\ce{C21H24F3N3}$) and a molar mass (375.44 g/mol) corresponding to the trimer with three molecules of HF.
I don't think you can rely on the CAS-No for this set of substances. You would have to go into the literature (this might be a starting point: https://www.sid.ir/paper/545317/en) and find out how they made or purchased a given reagent for a given use. You might also find whether the material is cross-linked and what the average molar mass is.

I came across the Synthesis article this afternoon. I think you might be right, that one just refers to the stoichiometric, and the other the non-stoichiometric HF-containing polymer. In other words, one CAS might refer to the polymer 'charged' with HF, while the other refers to the HF-depleted polymer. They're just not very clearly defined...
